# Какие есть api для поиска по картинке?

Tags: javascript, изображения, поиск-api

Мне нужен api для поиска по картинке. В просторах сети очень много разных советов для решения этого вопроса. И большинство из них устарели а другая часть просто не то, что нужно.  В первую очередь мне нужен бесплатный api.  Во вторую он должен искать именно по файлу а не строковому запросу.  Везде говорят о customsearch от google. Но в документации нет ни единого слова о том как искать именно по файлу а не по словам.  На данный момент у меня есть скрипт который ищет по ссылке картинки. Но этот вариант может не сработать если картинка находится на своем сервере и в ссылке будет не домен а ip сервера(я просто не уверен). Может ктото сталкивался с подобной задачей и есть альтернативы?

Answer (score 0):

Каждый файл, опубликованный в веб сети, имеет веб-адрес. Вы можете применять для повышения видимости ваших картинок, структурированную разметку из библиотеки Schema:

- **[image](http://schema.org/image)**
- **[ImageObject](http://schema.org/ImageObject)**
- **[ImageGallery](http://schema.org/ImageGallery)**

Также вы можете создавать сериализацию для ваших картинок с применением файлов **[XInclude](https://www.w3.org/TR/xinclude/)** как **[InfoSet](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-infoset/)**. Дополнительно смотрите о **[бинарной оптимизации файлов InfoSet с XOP](https://www.w3.org/TR/xop10/)**.

Comment: Это уж сооовсем не по теме.  Я не оптимизирую свои картинки.  Более того они вообще не должны быть доступны для поиска.  Я ищу картинки в сети

Comment: Извините, но я так понял ваш вопрос. Возможно вам помогут эти линки:  https://developer.yahoo.com/search/image/V1/imageSearch.html + https://www.flickr.com/services/api/ + https://developers.google.com/custom-search/

Comment: Customsearch,как я уже выше говорил, по файлу не ищет. А яху видимо уже закрыт.  На фликере поканичего не нашел относительно именно поиска но я покапаюсь там. Спасибо